# Unable to read a file from HDFS using spark shell in ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have installed spark and hadoop in standalone modes on ubuntu virtualbox for my learning. I am able to do normal hadoop mapreduce operations on hdfs without using spark. But when I use below code in spark-shell,

```
val file=sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/in/file")
scala>file.count()
```

I get **"input path does not exist."** error. The core-site.xml has fs.defaultFS with value hdfs://localhost:9000. If I give localhost without the port number, I get "Connection refused" error as it is listening on default port 8020. Hostname and localhost are set to loopback addresses 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.1.1 in etc/hosts.
Kindly let me know how to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: try this in terminal `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/in/`. Is file available?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to read and write into the hdfs using

```
"hdfs://localhost:9000/user/<user-name>/..."
```

Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 0):

Probably your configuration is alright, but the file is missing, or in an unexpected
location...

1) try:

```
sc.textFile("hdfs://in/file")
sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/<USERNAME>/in/file")
```

with USERNAME=hadoop, or your own username

2) try on the command line (outside spark-shell) to access that directory/file :

```
hdfs dfs -ls /in/file
```